# Accessing property that is filled by an AsyncTask returns null

Tags: java, android, oop

I am trying to get values from my User class (holding all the user information for the logged in user.
It is set once logged in, and it is printing out in the log just fine, but then when calling from the class that instantiates it, it returns a null? Here is the code:

```
public ApiConnector api;
public String ID;
public String USERNAME = null;
public String NAME = null;
public String LASTNAME = null;
public String PASSWORD = null;
public String EMAIL = null;

public User(String id) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.api = new ApiConnector();
    new GetUserDataClass().execute(api);
}
private class GetUserDataClass extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Boolean,JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
        return params[0].getAllUserData(ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        if(jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject();
                    json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(!json.getString("username").isEmpty()) {
                        setUsername(json.getString("username"));
                        Log.d("username", getUsername());
                    }
                    if(!json.getString("firstname").isEmpty()) {
                        setName(json.getString("firstname"));
                        Log.d("name", getName());
                    }
                    if(!json.getString("lastname").isEmpty()) {
                        setLastName(json.getString("lastname"));
                        Log.d("lastname", getLastName());
                    }
                    if(!json.getString("email").isEmpty()) {
                        setEmail(json.getString("email"));
                        Log.d("email", getEmail());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("hey", "hey");
        }
    }
```

The logcat output is:

```
05-19 02:03:55.996: W/EGL_emulation(4367): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-19 02:03:55.996: D/username(4367): Me
05-19 02:03:55.996: D/name(4367): Me
05-19 02:03:55.996: D/lastname(4367): Mememe
05-19 02:03:55.996: D/email(4367): me@example.com
```

I have all appropriate getters and setters in the class (as you can see in the above code, working fine.

Here is the Menu class (that is returning the null):

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

private String ID;
private User user;
public TextView tvusername;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    init();
}
public void init() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ID = bundle.getString("id");
    user = new User(ID);
    tvusername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
    tvusername.setText(ID + " " + user.getEmail());     
}   
}
```

Here is what it looks like on the emulator:

[image]

I have spent the last day and a half looking for solutions, but came up empty. Please would you help?

Comment: could You Show us what Your method getEmail() is doing?

Comment: create a pojo classes and pass the Class object and try.. i hope that mite solve your problem

Comment: it is returning the email, as shown in the logcat as it is instantiated

Comment: @RajeshM what is a pojo class?

Comment: class with private variable and public get() set() methods 

i,e: 
'public class MyBean {
 
    private String someProperty;
 
    public String getSomeProperty() {
         return someProperty;
    }
 
    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}'

Comment: @RajeshM thats what the user class is though?

Comment: you have to store that class object somewhere..and call the object ..

your creating a new User Class object which contains null .. 
your are not using the old class object which u assigned all the details ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53970/discussion-between-user3241507-and-rajesh-m).

Answer (score 0):

You are loading user data in an AsyncTask... and that's good because it seems to perform some network operation.

It means that user data loading is performed asynchronously... and so not available immediately.

You have a callback `onPostExecute` in the AsyncTask : use it to update the UI with something like this code :

```
//you need to initialize it in the AsyncTask constrtuctor
final Activity myActivity;
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
     //json parsing code
     //...
     //and finally update the UI
     new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
         new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                TextView tvusername = (TextView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
                tvusername.setText(ID + " " + getEmail());
             }
         }
     );
}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: `Handler cannot be resolved as a type`

Comment: `import android.os.Handler` and you also need to pass the Activity to your AsyncTask so that you can call `findViewById` (I will edit my post)

Comment: but I need to be able to user `User.getName();` etc throughut the app, now just `onPostExecute()`

Comment: You can't. As explained : the user data is not immediately available, so you must take care of that in your application code.

Comment: Just like in PHP, I cam creating a class to hold all the data to refer to at a later stage. I am setting variables in the User class and should be able to call those variables from another class, just like the methods, they return the variables that are set in the class, so I should be able to do that.

Comment: Yes, you can read the variables from your instance as soon as they are set. If you try to read the variables before they are inialized: you will only read null values. That's what I mean when I say that your application must take care of the fact that you never know when user-data is there (except AFTER clean execution of the onPostExecute). Please read this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    new GetUserDataClass().execute(api).get();
```

so that system will wait to complete AsyncTask. and you will get the id.

Comment: If for some reason the network operation takes too long : you will have an "Activity Not Responding" crash with this solution. Additionally : the UI will be unresponsive during the whole network operation.

Comment: This does not work, I had to surround with a try and catch as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to use static word in User class object creation while setting data.
other wise it will create new instance every time and that object will not show your data.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using the Singleton Design Pattern in my `User` class. Just so people can look that up to solve this if they are having the same issues!

Cheers and thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Why down vote? it is a method to solve it? and I am the poster of the question?